# Can't run NodeSchool workshops in Git Bash. "TypeError: process.stdin.setRawMode is not a function"

Tags: node.js, git, bash, console, tty

From the research I did for the topic, I saw some recommendations to install tty.js with npm, but it wouldn't install as well - some sort of python exe missing from the system error.

I am able to run the program from Git CMD but it is all confusing for me because I am familiar with unix based consoles :(

The way I installed node.js and npm : All was doen with the installer provided by node.js.

Any insights? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have installed tty.js in a linux enviroment and it works great, you should some building essentials installed, such as:

- gcc
- g++
- make

As well as Python 2.7. When installing using npm, it will look for all the dependencies and as I understand it will compile some C code that does the magic behind the scenes. I haven't tried it on Windows, but what I have seen there is the C code designed for windows, so it probably will run.

Maybe I will be of more help if you copy what you get on the npm installation.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using Git Bash? That is what I used for the most part as well and acts more unix like. If you're on a PC, an alternative is using ConEMU as they give you a shell that is unix like. Just wanted to give you some options if you're still running into trouble, I know this is super late :)